# Can inset faces be used on a triangular face?

Tags: mesh, interface

I have a triangular object created by merging two edges of a cube.  The object is a thick triangle of constant thickness.

I would like to do an even inset one of the triangular faces.

When I try the inset lines cross an

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inset... Use the inset tool.

Select the faces and Press <kbd>I</kbd> and drag to get the desired width.

[image]

Be careful to avoid making the inset much wider than the distance to the center of the face, or you'll get errors like these:
[image]